How do I test the result of a function in an MS Access macro
I am trying to pass a post code to a function I have created.
I need the function to return VALID if the post code is valid.
I then want to test the return to display an error message if not valid.
My function is:
Public Function IsUKPostCode(strInput As String)
'
' Uses a regular expression to validate the format of a postcode.
'
Dim RgExp As Object
Set RgExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
'
' Clear the function value
'
IsUKPostCode = ""
'
' Check if we have a value to test
'
If strInput = "" Then
  IsUKPostCode = "No Post Code entered"
  Exit Function
End If
'
' This is the regular expression that validates the postcode
RgExp.Pattern = "^[A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,2}[A-Z]?\s\d[A-Z]{2}$"
'
' Does the input string match the pattern?
'
If RgExp.Test(strInput) = True Then
  IsUKPostCode = "Valid"
  End If
End Function

I call the function from an MS Access macro using:
RunCode IsUKPostCode([Forms]![People maintenance]![People.Post Code]
I then want to test the return result to display a message.
Can anyone help with the correct If statement please?
Description above is sufficient.

It would possibly be easier to do that completely with VBA Code.
Anyway, here is a way to do it with an Access Macro. First of all it might be a good idea a to add an Else clause to your function to have a return value for both cases
Public Function IsUKPostCode(strInput As String) As String
    ' Uses a regular expression to validate the format of a postcode.
    Dim RgExp As Object
    Set RgExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
    ' Clear the function value
    IsUKPostCode = ""
    
    ' Check if we have a value to test
    If strInput = "" Then
        IsUKPostCode = "No Post Code entered"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' This is the regular expression that validates the postcode
    RgExp.Pattern = "^[A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,2}[A-Z]?\s\d[A-Z]{2}$"
    
    ' Does the input string match the pattern?
    If RgExp.Test(strInput) = True Then
        IsUKPostCode = "Valid"
    Else
        IsUKPostCode = "Invalid Post Code"
    End If
End Function

Use the Function in the Macro
In your MS Access macro, you want to call the function, store the result, and then display a message based on the result.
You can do this by:
Creating a Temporary Variable: Use a temporary variable to store the return value of IsUKPostCode.
Using an If Statement: Based on the value of this variable, display an appropriate message.
Here’s how you can set it up:
a. Create a Temporary Variable in the Macro
Go to the Macro Design view.

Create a new SetTempVar action to store the result of the function:

Name: PostCodeResult (or any other meaningful name)

Expression: IsUKPostCode([Forms]![People maintenance]![People.Post Code])


b. Add a Conditional Statement
After setting the temporary variable, use the If action to check the value of PostCodeResult:

Condition: [TempVars]![PostCodeResult] = "Valid"

If the condition is true, use the MessageBox action to display a message like "Post Code is valid."

Add an Else clause to display a different message if the post code is not valid:

MessageBox: "Invalid Post Code entered."


c. Clean Up Temporary Variables
After the If statement, use RemoveTempVar to clean up the temporary variable PostCodeResult

Thanks Storax. Could you please check your response, its just the function IsUKPostCode now seems to be running twice and the condition does not seem to be "Invalid"

I amended the VBA code to

You have to remove your original line RunCode IsUKPostCode([Forms]![People maintenance]![People.Post Code] from your macro. I guess that's the issue. Otherwise please elaborate!

Yes, I did that and that fixed that problem. The problem now is the temp var looks as if it is not being set

IsUKPostCode is being set correctly in the function to Valid or Invalid

Apologies Storax, I had defined the variable as setlocalvar and not settempvar. All works great now, many thanks for your help
